# Retrieve IQueryable Result in Public Methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

Is it a valid architeture to declare public methods that retrieve IQueryable results like below :

```
public IQueryable GetData()
```

Comment: In which context? Better to name it `GetQuery()`. Not that `IQueryable` become invalid when context is disposed.

Comment: This can cause difficulties with unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, but please be aware that with IQueryable (just like IEnumerable, IList or ICollection) you need to include the type:

Generic:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetData()
```

String:

```
public IQueryable<string> GetData()
```

Remember that IQueryable (just like all the previous mentioned interfaces) inherits from IEnumerable.